# change columns when screen resolution change

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, width

I have a table connected with a database and this table has 3 columns in each row and I am using CSS.
when resolution become lower I want to have 1 column in each row

**I am using @media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width:916px)

Comment: This is not a question and not even a problem description. What is your problem ? What are you expecting from us ? What have you tried hitherto ?

Comment: I need to change all table when resolution become lower (like open it from mobiles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render two tables... one in your 3-colums layout and one in your mobile layout. Depending on your screen size, you can show the first and hide the second one via media query. This is not the best solution but it works :)

Redesign a table depending on screen size is a little bit tricky!

Here is a good tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/